# How can I get a list of available wireless networks on Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi

I would like to get a list of the wireless networks available. Ideally this would be via some C call, but I don't mind if I have to kludge it with a system call. Even better if the required C call or program doesn't require some exotic 3rd party package.

The internet seems to suggest I use `sudo iwlist <interface> scan` which does seem to do the trick from the command line, but I'd rather not require root permissions. I only want to see the basics, not change anything.

Comment: You do not need to be root to run iwlist, but it will only report the cached values from the last periodic scan.  To force a new scan you do need to be root.

Comment: Hmm, when run non-root it returns nothing, at least on Ubuntu 8.04 :-/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [Wireless Tools](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) package -- of which [iwlist](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/iwlist8.html) is a part -- also contains a Wireless Tools Helper Library. You need to include **iwlib.h** and link with **libiw.a** (i.e. add -liw). Then look up the documentation for the **iw_set_ext** function. The **SIOCSIWSCAN** parameter will be of most use. For an example of how to use this interface, take a look at the KWifiManager source in the KDE library (see: [Interface_wireless_wirelessextensions::get_available_networks](http://websvn.kde.org/tags/KDE/3.5.0/kdenetwork/wifi/interface_wireless_wirelessextensions.cpp?view=markup) method). Alternatively, you can also download the [Wireless Tools source code](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/wireless_tools.29.tar.gz) and take a look at how the iwlib iw_set_ext function is also used for scanning in iwlist.c.

As for privileges, I imagine the process will need to run as root to perform the scan. I'd love to know if this could be done otherwise as well.

Since you are using Ubuntu 8.04 the [libiw-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/libiw-dev) package should be of use.

Comment: Can I use **Wirelsess Tool** package (**libiw-dev**) in commercial application? Probably I can't, but I want be sure.

Answer (score 41):

It's pretty easy to do a scan in the command line. The man pages are your friend here (check out **iwconfig** and **iwlist**). But using the C interface is a little more difficult so I'll focus on that.

First of all, as other people have mentioned, definitely download out the [wireless tools source code](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html#latest). All the documentation for the programming interface is in the **.c** files. As far as I can tell, there is no web documentation for the api. However, the source code is pretty easy to read through. You pretty much only need **iwlib.h** and **iwlib.c** for this question.

While you can use `iw_set_ext` and `iw_get_ext`, the **libiw** implements a basic scanning function `iw_scan`, from which you can extract most of the information that you need.

Here is a simple program to get the ESSID for all available wireless networks. Compile with `-liw` and run with `sudo`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iwlib.h>

int main(void) {
  wireless_scan_head head;
  wireless_scan *result;
  iwrange range;
  int sock;

  /* Open socket to kernel */
  sock = iw_sockets_open();

  /* Get some metadata to use for scanning */
  if (iw_get_range_info(sock, "wlan0", &range) < 0) {
    printf("Error during iw_get_range_info. Aborting.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  /* Perform the scan */
  if (iw_scan(sock, "wlan0", range.we_version_compiled, &head) < 0) {
    printf("Error during iw_scan. Aborting.\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  /* Traverse the results */
  result = head.result;
  while (NULL != result) {
    printf("%s\n", result->b.essid);
    result = result->next;
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

DISCLAIMER: This is just a demonstration program. It's possible for some results to not have an essid. In addition, this assumes your wireless interface is "wlan0". You get the idea.

Read the **iwlib** source code!

Comment: Can you also get the AP address (mac address) using this method?
How? Thanks :)

Comment: I get the MAC address with: result->ap_addr but it is not in a printable form. It prints out something like 71732.

Comment: **iwconfig** prints out the access point in the usual format. Check out the source code for the command in `iwconfig.c` (search for "Access Point").

Comment: @DavidMatlack, is the first one in the list the one which I am currently connected?

Comment: @MattLong You are not connected to any at this time. The card is scanning.

Comment: @DavidMatlack, **What's the License**?

Comment: @DavidMatlack Is it possible to make this run without sudo?

Comment: I am completely unable to get this to link. Although the iw library is installed on two different platforms I get :gcc -liw -o scan scan.o
/usr/bin/ld: scan.o: in function `main':
scan.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `iw_sockets_open'
/usr/bin/ld: scan.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `iw_get_range_info'
/usr/bin/ld: scan.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `iw_scan'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nmcli` which does not require root permissions or name of WIFI interface.

```
nmcli -t -f ssid dev wifi
```