# Connect to wifi network in Linux using c++ library

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to develop a wifi interface for a linux app in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I tried to use two different libraries:

1. NetworkManager.
   At the moment, unable to install it in Ubuntu 14.04 asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841666/installing-networkmanager-leaves-ubuntu-14-04-without-internet)
2. Wireless Tools. Found information on how to perform a scan in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400240/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-available-wireless-networks-on-linux). Succeeded using the library to perform a scan using the answer from @David Matlack but I'm unable to understand the library in order to connect or disconnect to any network.

Has someone succeeded using any of these libraries? Some code example on how to connect would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same problem, same results, still the same in 2017.